# Is it safe to use both MSVCR120.dll and MSVCR90.dll in same application?

Tags: c++, windows

We are using two 3rd party .dlls from the same company.
According to Dependency Walker `first.dll` loads `MSVCR120.dll` and `second.dll` which in turn loads `MSVCR90.dll`.

I understand that this is potentially dangerous since the two CRTs have different heaps?
So for instance if memory is allocated via `malloc()` in one CRT and `free()`d in the other this may cause heap corruption.

But can these two CRT ever be used this way in a perfectly safe manner?

My reason for asking is that our program sometimes crashes at start-up and the dump file tells us that the cause is heap corruption.
We are not sure if this is due to bugs in our code or in 3rd party .dlls that we use.

Comment: With different heaps you need to carefully look at/design the DLL interfaces.  The interfaces needs be pure `C`.  Creating and freeing any heap memory needs to be done in the appropriate DLL via helper functions.  This means no use of std::"anything" in the DLL interfaces including the throwing of exceptions.

Comment: ***So for instance if memory is allocated via malloc() in one CRT and free()d in the other this may cause heap corruption.*** Yes I believe you will have to isolate the allocation and freeing of memory to the same heap meaning you can't allocate memory in one heap and free it in a different heap.

Comment: _We are using two 3rd party .dlls from the same company_ I would ask them to supply a product fit for purpose.  These two DLLs should not be using different versions of the runtime.

Comment: @PaulSanders: can you think of any reason why they would need to do this? I find this very strange and would think that they would build all their .dlls against the same CRT.

Comment: These are both very old and for outdated versions of msvc. Don't they have an update to the dlls? Or is this some field like medical where updates are very slow because of regulations.

Comment: _"...can you think of any reason why they would need to do this..."_ either the products are no long supported, or they rely on other 3rd partly libraries which have not been updated.  Either way they might not be able to offer you any support going forwards, time to look for a possible replacement.

Comment: if you can't find a replacement then you need to split the thing into 2 processes, each running separate versions of the DLLs, and interact with each other via IPC. But in that case better rewrite the lib on your own